# remove qcow2 image file's holes

Tags: qemu, hole-punching

I use a tool named virt-sparsify to free disk space a qcow2 image file occupies.

It works and the file becomes a sparse file.

```
root@ubuntu:/test# ls -lsh test.qcow2

8.7G -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 15G Jan 19 11:05 test.qcow2
```

As shown above, the disk size allocated for the file is smaller than its actual size. It means there are “holes” in the file. Now I want to remove these holes inside it. Does anyone know how to achieve this purpose？

Answer (score 1):

You can't really "take away" the sparse flag.
Tools try to help by keeping the flag alive e.g. cp when copying.

You can easily get a non-sparse version of that file via

```
cp --sparse=never test.qcow2 test-nosparse.qcow2
```

The same way you can make a partially zeroed out file a sparse file

```
cp --sparse=always file.qcow2 file-sparse.qcow2
```

See "sparse" in [man cp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree with you. Sparse files have the advantage of saving disk space. But we need to be careful when transfer sparse files. Because some  tools do not support  sparse file and will convert it into a common file,for example, scp. And I doubt what will happen when transfer sparse files between different file systems.